# Android Bluetooth Sniff Mode

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing an Android app that has a Bluetooth service.  The Android phone, will be the master in the system and initiate the connection.  I have been able to to get the Bluetooth device to pair and connect with on an Android phone running Android 4.1.2 and a tablet with 4.2.0.  I am also able to send and receive data. But the issue I am having is that the Bluetooth device wants to be in sniff mode with the Android phone or tablet.  The phone and tablet do not respond back in going into sniff mode it appears and the Bluetooth device drops the connection.

The Bluetooth stack up to Android 4.2 has been the Bluez BT Stack.  Now on Android 4.2 Google developed a new BT Stack.  The Bluez BT Stack website or even the Android Developer website is not very helpful at all to try to correlate the BT Stack version to Android API.

1.) How do you find the version of the BT Stack in the Android version and the documentation for it?

2.) Is there away to enable sniff mode on the android device? or does the BT Stack take care of this?

Thanks,
-Nick

Comment: 1. Android JB onwards, bluez stack is not supported and is replaced by broadcomm stack, framework API would remain same and ideally should not impact application developer
2.Bluetooth stack takes care of putting device info sniff/park mode

Comment: Does it matter who requests sniff mode? (i.e the phone to the BT device, or from the BT device to the phone?)  The device I am talking to is the one making the request to go to sniff mode, and for all I know I also thought that the Bluetooth stack would take care of this.

Comment: Yes, bluetooth stack takes care of putting device in sniff mode, application need not have to ask to stack

Comment: So if sniff mode is not established between the BT device and the Phone, where the BT device is expected to have this negotiated.  Then this most likely would mean that the BT stack on the phone does not support the request that the BT device is asking. Like the timing could be non-standard?  If that is the case, would I need to go into the BT stack onto the phone and change things around?

Comment: The new stack is bluedroid http://lwn.net/Articles/597293/