# Bluetooth "Sniff Mode"

Tags: java, android, sniffing

I'm developing an app which connects one Android device with another device via SPP.

I have a problem on my connection: Lag.
My first communication gets an immediate response.
The next ones take more time because my Android device goes into a "Sniff Mode".

How can i get rid of this?

Edit:
This is the 1st communication:
[1stComm](http://s7.postimg.org/nrmafivh7/comm1.jpg)

This is the second one:
[2ndComm](http://s18.postimg.org/x5xv8bqzd/comm2.jpg)

Comment: can you identify and show us the code that is responsible for your problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741982/android-bluetooth-sniff-mode

Comment: You may need to swap what stack you are using

Comment: I edited my post and u can see data flow from wireshark

Comment: Riley I saw that post but it didnt help me at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved]
I was sending more bytes to the device that I should. (i.e. had a byte array with 2000 bytes, message had 20 bytes, sent 20 bytes + 1980 zeros and the device got mad with those zeros).